# AzSK anyway to remove org policy?

Tags: azure-security

I have installed a custom policy using AzSKOrganizationPolicy something like this

```
Install-AzSKOrganizationPolicy -SubscriptionId <SubscriptionId> `
    -OrgName "Contoso" `
    -DepartmentName "IT" `
    -PolicyFolderPath "D:\ContosoPolicies"
```

Is there any way to remove the custom policy configured for subscription? To return  back to org-neutral policy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are multiple ways, First is to :
Update-AzSKOrganizationPolicy -SubscriptionId  `-OrgName "Contoso"`
-DepartmentName "IT" `
-PolicyFolderPath "D:\ContosoPolicies"

And revert the changes you made, The orignal config can be found at, [Azsk Github](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit)

2. 2nd way is to remove/delete the modules and download AzSK again.